# channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused - 16.04

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two ubuntu machines with 16.04

- ikayyy@ubuntuPC:~$ (test-PC) > 172.16.61.16/24
- ik@ik0:~$ (main-PC) > 172.16.61.14/24

From my main-PC, I would like to access the GUI of test-PC.

On the test-PC, modified "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file, and added > "AllowTcpForwarding yes" field in the file and restarted the ssh services.

Since, both the machines are in the same network I didn't add any routes.

When I run this command: **ik@ik0:~$ ssh -vv -4 ikayyy@172.16.61.16 -L 8091:localhost:80** it connects to the test-PC well.

But when I try accessing the GUI via trying > localhost:8091 in the browser, it shows the errors, attached in a text file.
[the logs attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SVmHuNvGk2VPEDHtuoBKZBm46SzELP4G/view?usp=sharing)

If someone please help me accessing the GUI of the other machine i will be grateful.